# Data not getting into Angular Material dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a simple Angular Material dialog which is supposed to display some data about a person. The person object I am displaying is below:

```
export interface Person {
   prsName: string;
   prsAddress: string;
   prsCity: string;
   prsState: string;
}
```

The Typescript code for the dialog is below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-persondialog',
  templateUrl: './persondialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./persondialog.component.css']
})
export class PersonDialogComponent {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PersonDialogComponent>,
          @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public theInfo: Person) {
             alert('Name: '+theInfo.prsName); /*  temporary call to check the contents of theInfo */
          }

  onClose(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
 }
```

The function for opening the dialog, called from my main component, is below:

```
  public getPerson(aName: string) {
     const found = this.persGetter.findPerson(aName);

     found.subscribe(info => {
       alert('Person Name: ' + info.prsName + ' Address: ' + info.prsAddress); /* Temporary. This just shows that info has real data! */
       const ref = this.theDlg.open(PersonDialogComponent, {
         width: '300px',
         data: { theInfo: info }
       });
     });
   }
```

note that persGetter is an HttpClient object that gets Person information from my server.

The HTML for the dialog is below:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Person: {{ theInfo.prsName }}</h1>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="onClose()">Close</button>
</div>
```

The dialog displays when the getPerson() function is called, but for some reason, between the time that the alert displays the contents of info and the actual creation of the dialog, the prsName property becomes undefined!

Clearly I am missing something. Can anyone tell me how I can get my Person info to be successfully passed into this dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the open code to this:

```
   const ref = this.theDlg.open(PersonDialogComponent, {
     width: '300px',
     data: info
   });
```

For better 'logging':

```
  constructor(
      public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PersonDialogComponent>,
      @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public theInfo: Person
  ) {
      console.info(JSON.stringify(theInfo, null, 4)); 
  }
```

Comment: Marc: I was aware of the proper use of console for logging; unfortunately my environment has a problem where console output doesn't always appear, hence the use of temporary alert boxes. Still, your solution is the simplest and most effective, so the alerts are removed from my code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is width the way you pass the data. You need to pass the complete data as a JSON. Refer this [link](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples) for more details. theInfo is your object name and not the data itself.

To pass the object data, you need to modify your call to dialog as below

public getPerson(aName: string) {
     const found = this.persGetter.findPerson(aName);

```
 found.subscribe(info => {
   alert('Person Name: ' + info.prsName + ' Address: ' + info.prsAddress); /* Temporary. This just shows that info has real data! */
   const ref = this.theDlg.open(PersonDialogComponent, {
     width: '300px',
     data: { prsName: info.prsName }
   });
 });
```

}

This will pass the object of type Person to the dialog as required.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access wrong property,

use this

```
 constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PersonDialogComponent>,
          @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public theInfo: any) {
             alert('Name: '+theInfo.theInfo.prsName); // as you are passing { theInfo: info }
          }
```

or pass just info not an object

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PersonDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public theInfo: Person) {
                 alert('Name: '+theInfo.prsName); // as you are passing info here
              }

const ref = this.theDlg.open(PersonDialogComponent, {
         width: '300px',
         data: info 
       });
```